# Authetication system for 1 user - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have only one user for my asp.net application and I have to create the authentication system for the website. What could be the best, secure and easiest way I can do that?

What I believe that createing a table in a database for a single user is not at all a good choice. At the same time, security is the major need for the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the username and (hashed) password in the web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e01fc50a.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have to worry about user maintenance, just add the user to the local system and establish integrated windows authentication. This keeps the password secure, the login is done through NTLM, and you can use the built-in Identity class to keep track of the logged in user.

Comment: Thanks. As I am completely new to this authentication scheame. Can you guide me to the right tutorial to start with? Will it provide me the change password service?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - no it'll provide no user maintenance features at all. If you wanted to do that from within the website, you'd have to code that into a library or webpage. If you're looking for out of the box authentication with self-service user features, I'd recommend you use the SQL Membership provider database. While the tables may seem like a "waste", it'll actually end up being easier to manage.